# When inserting and deleting rows in a tableView, how do I prevent it trying to add them at invalid locations?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Let's say I have a tableView section with just 2 cells, Username and Password. If I tap either of those cells, I want to add another cell directly beneath them (with info on valid usernames, etc.) Only one of the detail cells should be visible at once, so if the username one is open and I tap password, the username one will be deleted, and the password one will be added.

I'm having an issue where if the username one is open, and I tap password, the app crashes. It's trying to insert a cell at indexPath.row 3 (since at that time, there's username at 0, the username detail at 1, and password at 2. However, a delete has just occurred, and by that time the username detail is gone, so it's trying to insert at 3, when it should actually be inserting at 2.

What can I do here? This whole cell updating thing seems insanely complicated for what should be such a simple operation.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPathToDelete = self.controlRowIndexPath;

    if ([indexPath isEqual:self.tappedIndexPath]) {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
        self.tappedIndexPath = nil;
        self.controlRowIndexPath = nil;

        if (indexPath.section == 0) self.cellDetailOpenInSection0 = NO;
        else if (indexPath.section == 1) self.cellDetailOpenInSection1 = NO;
        else self.cellDetailOpenInSection2 = NO;

    } else {
        self.tappedIndexPath = indexPath;
        self.controlRowIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:indexPath.section];

        if (indexPath.section == 0) self.cellDetailOpenInSection0 = YES;
        else if (indexPath.section == 1) self.cellDetailOpenInSection1 = YES;
        else self.cellDetailOpenInSection2 = YES;
    }

    [self.userPassTableView beginUpdates];

    if (indexPathToDelete) {
        [self.userPassTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPathToDelete] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        if (indexPathToDelete.section == 0) self.cellDetailOpenInSection0 = NO;
        else if (indexPathToDelete.section == 1) self.cellDetailOpenInSection1 = NO;
        else if (indexPathToDelete.section == 2) self.cellDetailOpenInSection2 = NO;
    }

    if (self.controlRowIndexPath) {
        [self.userPassTableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.controlRowIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        if (self.controlRowIndexPath.section == 0) self.cellDetailOpenInSection0 = YES;
        else if (self.controlRowIndexPath.section == 1) self.cellDetailOpenInSection1 = YES;
        else if (self.controlRowIndexPath.section == 2) self.cellDetailOpenInSection2 = YES;
    }

    // Trying to insert one at a location that no longer exists because it just deleted one.

    [self.userPassTableView endUpdates];

}
```

Comment: Can u share the dataSource delegate methods too like numberOfRowsInSection: please. So that I can clear my doubt about ur problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if there will only be two cells you don't need to make this overly complex. What I would do is use `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` and begin/end updates to do the heavy lifting for me.

First, set up your each of your cells to display the username/password label/textfield/whatever you want on their top half, and the "details" on the bottom half.

[image]

Then just modify `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` to by default return a value that will only expose the top half of the cell and only conditionally be large enough to reveal the entire cell. From there all you have to do is a little indexPath comparison and you're golden.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.currentIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:NSIntegerMax inSection:0];
}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ([indexPath compare:self.currentIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame) {
        return 100.0f;
    }
    return 44.0f;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    if ([indexPath compare:self.currentIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame) {
        self.currentIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:NSIntegerMax inSection:0];
    }else{
        self.currentIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:indexPath.section];
    }

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

Comment: I tried both solutions (changing height / inserting & deleting) and changing height is a lot easier. Inserting & deleting cells introduces a lot of problems because all the indices are constantly changing.

Comment: @Sulthan Indeed, especially when there are only two cells to worry about.

Comment: I'm going to give this approach a little thought. There are actually three groups, two of two, and one of three.

Comment: @lukech Alright, let me know how it goes! And if that's how many cells you're using you still should have to worry about performance with this method. However, if you want to further optimize, you could make a hybrid between this solution and the original. Maybe create the view that houses the details for that cell on the fly and only add it when the cell is selected, and then remove it upon deselection. This could probably be accomplished easily by subclassing the cell.

Comment: MUCH nicer. I have a few hairs left, and I'm naming them after you.

Comment: @lukech glad it worked, and thanks for making me laugh in the middle of math class!!